# Problema con campo vacío en formulario

Tags: laravel

Hice una migración y la tabla `change` es de tipo `integer` y le coloqué la función `default()` ya que el campo podrían dejarlo vacío y quiero que por defecto me lo guarde con el valor `cero`, cuando completo el formulario me da el siguiente error: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'change' cannot be null`

Aí defino el campo en la migración:

```
$table->integer('change')->default(0);
```

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        Badge::create([
            'shop_id' => $request['shop_id'],
            'payment_number' => $request['payment_number'],
            'code' => $request['code'],
            'change' => $request['change'],
            'total' => $request['total'],
            'status' => 0,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Cuando quieras insertar (no sé como lo estás haciendo) **no** debes pasarle esa columna. Posiblemente se la estés pasando con valor `null`.

Comment: Nos muestras tu query de inserción por favor?

Comment: actualicé la pregunta

Comment: Hago un `dd()` para ver lo que envía y lo envía null (está vacío el campo) `"change" => null`

Comment: Una idea sería hacer esto en el change `'change' => $request['change'] ?? 0,` indicamos un *condicional*, ¿qué opinas @porloscerrosΨ?

Comment: Gracias, con esa explicación se me ocurrió también otra solución `if($request['change'] == NULL) { $request['change'] = 0;}`

Comment: genial @Joseph la tenía en la mente pero primero quise hacer pruebas y posterior te propongo una solución

Comment: @BetaM Sí, puede ser también, pero creo que sería redundante con el valor por default de la columna en BD. Creo que el controlador no tiene por qué saber cuál es el valor, entonces si cambia en la BD, no será necesario cambiarlo en la aplicación. O sea, la responsabilidad del valor por default en este caso, es de la BD, y no de la aplicación.

Comment: Concuerdo contigo totalmente @porloscerrosΨ y externo que tu solución me parece la indicada en este caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como le estás pasando el nombre de la columna con valor `null`, el método `create` intentará insertar ese valor y la columna no acepta valores `null`. Si quieres que tome el valor por default, no debes pasarle esa columna cuando insertas.

Una forma de resolverlo puede ser preparando el array de datos en una variable, y condicionalmente mergear el elemento `change`.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'shop_id' => $request['shop_id'],
        'payment_number' => $request['payment_number'],
        'code' => $request['code'],
        'total' => $request['total'],
        'status' => 0,
    ];
    if ($request['change'])
        $data = array_merge($data, [ 'change' => $request['change'] ]);
    Badge::create($data);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te decía en los comentarios, pudieras considerar valerte de la característica llamada [Null coalescing operator de PHP 7+](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) que te da las siguientes características:

- Azúcar sintáctica para no emplear de forma directa un operador ternario
- No ocupas de **forma directa** a la función `isset()`
- Asigna en este caso como valor del registro el valor del request si este existe y no es nulo y en caso contrario otorga como valor lo que pongamos al extremo que sería el valor 0

Quedando así:

```
'change' => $request['change'] ?? 0
```